# angular 2 RC 5 handling return values from Http.Post(..)

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a generic post method created in angular 2 RC 5 using typescript in an injectable class called AppService. Just the Post method here below:

```
  post(url, data, options?: RequestOptionsArgs ): Promise<any> {

    var opt = this.createHeaders(options);

    return this.http.post(url, data, opt)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as any)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

I am calling this generic post method of the AppService in my component like this:

```
 export class myComponent implements OnInit {

    result : MyServiceResult;
    userModel: UserModel;

    constructor(private router: Router, private service: AppService) {
        this.userModel = new UserModel();
        this.result = new MyServiceResult();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

       getValue(): void { 

            var rowid = this.userModel.rowid;
            var serviceTag = this.userModel.serviceTag;

            var data = JSON.stringify({ rowid, serviceTag });
            console.log(data);
            this.service.post('api/Dutch', data, null)
                    .then(t => this.result = t     )  ;

            console.log('value returned: '+ this.result.ExpiryDate);

        }

}
```

The service endpoint written in web api 2 gets hit and on the service side I see the values getting returned so its not an issue with the service. On the client side I get this message.

> value returned: undefined

What am I missing?

Comment: Since your request will be executed asynchronously, the result will actually be undefined until you get the response. try putting console.log inside `then`

Comment: Can you try it as `this.service.post('api/Dutch', data, null).then(t => {this.result = t; console.log('value returned: '+ this.result.ExpiryDate);})  ;`

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ExpiryDate' of undefined